# AWS API authentication in R : Missing Authentication Token

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, httr

I need to authenticate AWS API in R. I tried using aws.signature package to do the same and I am getting 403 response with error **Missing Authentication Token** . It seems that I am missing some necessary parameters. Looking for assistance to debug the below code or ways to authenticate AWS API in R.

```
# To create aws signature for authentication for the rest API call

library(aws.signature)
library(httr)

# validate arguments and setup request URL
current <- Sys.time()
d_timestamp <- format(current, "%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ", tz = "UTC")

hdrs <- list(`Content-Type` = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
         Host = "jteti5wnje.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
         `x-amz-date` = d_timestamp)

params <- signature_v4_auth(
datetime = d_timestamp,
              region = "eu-central-1",
              service = "execute-api",
              verb = "GET",
              action = "iMetaAPI",
              query_args = list(),
              canonical_headers = hdrs,
              request_body = "json",
              key = "***************",
              secret = "*****************",
              session_token = NULL,
              query = FALSE,
              algorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256",
              verbose = TRUE)


a <- GET("https://jteti5wnje.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/iMetaAPI",
query = params)

rawToChar(a$content)
```

Comment: It might be part of the function itself, but i don't see you giving your signature param a name anywhere, only the value (as returned by signature_v4_auth).

Comment: @colde Thanks for the response Kindly elaborate what do you mean by i don't see you giving your signature param a name anywhere, only the value as I am having naive knowledge about the AWS signature.

Comment: normally url parmeters follow a key=value pattern. I don't see what you are naming your "key" part of that pattern. But i assume the value is set to the data returned som `signature_v4_auth`

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- `request_body` needs to be the actual body. You're doing a `GET()` so it should just be `NULL` or `""`.
- The response from `signature_v4_auth()` is a list but you don't need all of its elements - probably just the `hds$Authorization <- params$SignatureHeader` element.
- The actual errors you're getting is because you haven't passed the headers. You need to pass the headers to `GET()` with something like: `do.call(add_headers, hdrs)` so you can do:

  ```
  a <- GET("https://jteti5wnje.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/iMetaAPI", do.call(add_headers, headers))
  ```

That will probably work, or you'll at least get a more informative error.